# Gcovr - 6 possible branches in if-statement

Tags: gcov, gcovr

I am using Gcovr to measure code coverage in C++.
In a simple if-statement, I am getting weird results.

Below I add a picture of a code coverage.
Can anyone help and can explain, why there are six possible branches?
When I seperate the functions a() and b() in their own if-statement, I am getting two possible branches, which is ok.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could this be a bug in relation to lazy evaluation in `if`-statements?

Answer (score 1):

GCC-gcov code coverage does not consider the branches in your source code, it considers the branches emitted by the compiler. Approximately, it works on an assembly level. If I look at the assembly for your initial `func()`, I see three branching points associated with that line:

```
func():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    a()
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .L6
        call    b()
        test    eax, eax
        je      .L7
.L6:
        mov     eax, 1
        jmp     .L8
.L7:
        mov     eax, 0
.L8:
        test    al, al
        je      .L9
        mov     eax, 1
        jmp     .L10
.L9:
        mov     eax, 0
.L10:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

– https://godbolt.org/z/6q691r3fj gcc 12.2 with `-O0`

The entire `.L8` and `.L9` block look pretty pointless to me, but it seems to me that the compiler is actually  translating the conditional via an intermediate variable. Roughly, your code

```c
if (a() || b()) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

seems to be translated as

```c
int cond;
if (a() || b()) {
  cond = 1;
} else {
  cond = 0;
}

int retval;
if (cond) {
  retval = 1;
} else {
  retval = 0;
}

return retval;
```

This is just the kind of code that gets emitted when disabling all optimizations. It is not always a literal translation of the source code, sometimes compilers do stuff that appears really dumb. As discussed in the [gcovr FAQ entry “Why does C++ have so many uncovered branches?”](https://gcovr.com/en/master/faq.html#why-does-c-code-have-so-many-uncovered-branches), it is not generally possible to get rid of all the compiler-generated branches. As a consequence, chasing a concrete branch coverage metric is not overly useful for GCC-gcov based coverage data.